# which one is correct (have been or was)?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Which one is correct (have been or was)?

> I **have been receiving** allowance from the office from the above dates.

or

> I **was receiving** allowance from the office from the above dates.

Answer (score 1):

Which one is correct depends on your present situation. If you are still receiving an allowance from the office for "the above dates", the correct sentence is the first one: "I **have been receiving** allowance from the office from the above dates." This shows that you are still receiving an allowance from the office, and implies that you will continue to do so for some time in the future.

If you received an allowance from the office for "the above dates," but you are no longer receiving an allowance, then the correct sentence is the second one: "I **was receiving** allowance from the office from the above dates." This sentence means that you were receiving an allowance from the office for a period of time, but you are no longer receiving an allowance for "the above dates." If this second situation is the one that applies to your situation, I would phrase the sentence like this: "I **received** an allowance from the office **for** the above dates." This sentence is more concise, and it shows that you received an allowance from the office for a specified period of time (the above dates), but that you are no longer receiving an allowance for that period of time.

Answer (score 0):

"have been" refers to the past, and suggests that sometimes it's true, sometimes it's not, but it's occurred at least one time, as in - "I have been accused of doing bad things."  It is imperfect tense, so it usually comes with a qualifier "I have been accused of doing bad things while drinking."

"was" is more specific, and suggests something that happened and was completed in the past, as in - "I was accused of doing bad things."

There is not enough information in your question to know which is appropriate here.